# Integrating Slack with Uptime Robot Recomendations

Tags: slack-api, uptime-monitoring

Morning all

I am currently trying to get slack notifications when I have downtime or uptime using Uptime Robot

The methods I have found have used 3rd party downloads though and seem to be from 4/5 years ago?

Maybe I am just terrible at googling.

Any recommendations on how to do it or best practice?

Must be a way within uptime robot alone?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Uptime Robot suggests a method using [Slack's Incoming WebHooks](https://slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook), which seems to work for now, but Slack advises may be deprecated or removed at any time.

Here's how to set up Slack notifications in Uptime Robot:

1. In Uptime Robot, Go to My Settings -> Add Alert Contact -> Alert Contact Type: Slack

[image: Dialog box in Uptime Robot showing flow to Add Alert Contact for Slack]

2. In your desired Slack Workspace, you'll need to set up the [incoming webhook](https://slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook) to post to a particular channel. Once you do that, you'll receive a URL from Slack, which you'll need to provide back in Uptime Robot. Then you can save the new Slack Alert Contact.
3. In Uptime Robot, go to your desired Monitor, then Edit, then Select "Alert Contacts to Notify". Make sure the box is checked for your new Slack alert contact.

You can test the integration by selecting your desired Monitor, then running "Test notification setup". Note that this will alert ALL of your selected Alert Contacts for this monitor.

Comment: Also, wanted to validate that it was difficult to find this info from Uptime Robot. The comments on this blog post are what sent me in the right direction: https://blog.uptimerobot.com/adding-custom-text-to-slack-hipchat-notifications-now-possible/